# JVM Instrumentation - Prometheus - Netbeans Project Failure

Tags: java, netbeans, jvm, prometheus, metrics

I am new to NetBeans and Java in general and am probably doing something obviously wrong.

After downloading the Prometheus Metrics Library from Github the project fails to compile in NetBeans:

```
Prometheus Metrics Core ............................ FAILURE [  6.680 s]
```

(Skips compilation of any more modules after this point, compiles 8 or 9 prior modules without issue.)

```
Error: Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:2.12.4:test (default-test) on project prometheus-metrics-core: There are test failures.
```

The above plugin is present in the pom.xml file. I have tried various versions of surefire, 2.14.2 is the one it wants to use.

Environment:

Apache Maven 3.9.6 (bc0240f3c744dd6b6ec2920b3cd08dcc295161ae)
Maven home: C:\Program Files\apache-maven-3.9.6
Java version: 11.0.21, vendor: Oracle Corporation, runtime: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-11
Default locale: en_GB, platform encoding: Cp1252
OS name: "windows 10", version: "10.0", arch: "amd64", family: "windows"

I am trying to instrument a Server that has several JVMs so that Metrics can be scraped by either Grafana or Prometheus.  I am trying to compile the project on my laptop then insert it in the correct place within JBOSS to tell the JVMs to deliver metrics.

Any ideas?

Comment: [Markdown help](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help)